# Global middleware for Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I would like to add something like this to all my queries and mutations

```
type Query @middleware(checks: ["moduleCheck", "moduleScope"]){
  //
}
```

Is there a way to run middleware globally?

I can add it to the `$middleware` variable in `Http\Kernal.php` but then my middleware won't respond with the required queries set to `null`, which throws a different error.

Comment: Could you tell what you are trying to achieve with the global middleware? 

Lighthouse works by adding a route to Laravel routes, you can disable the default and register your own, by doing this, you can add all route middlewares you want. 
However it's a different story if you want to add the middlewares from lighthouse to all methods.

Comment: I would like to do the second, for example if I add the auth middleware to the route then you won't get graphql compliant error messages whereas if you add it as lighthouse middleware it is caught and converted.  I would like to do the same with my middleware, being able to throw exceptions that are caught by lighthouse and converted to graphql compliant errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put it inside middleware config in lighthouse.php like so

```
'middleware' => [

        \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Http\Middleware\AcceptJson::class,

        // Logs in a user if they are authenticated. In contrast to Laravel's 'auth'
        // middleware, this delegates auth and permission checks to the field level.
        \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Http\Middleware\AttemptAuthentication::class,

         \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddlewareGoesHere::class,
    ],
```

Comment: I am looking to add a middleware to all of my queries, the same way as using the `@middleware` directive.  It is somewhat confusing that these are also called middleware and have the same signature but they are run at a different point to the lighthouse.php middleware.  The critical difference is to do with whether errors are caught and graphQL errors returned or http errors.